# HTML/CSS/Jquery content side scroller

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to develop a new site and am looking for a content side scroller similar to http://www.brotips.com/ where you can use arrow keys/clicking the numbers underneath the content.

Is there any library's or tutorials you recommend, I cannot find a tutorial suitable for this sort of effect.

So far I have thought about doing it with

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll">
  <?php
  //Get the number of posts from mysql database and the posts and output to table
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)?

Comment: I don't believe they are using any kind of side scroller.  It looks to me like they are using server side pagination coupled with some added javascript to handle the arrow key presses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Google'd and found this, http://jqueryfordesigners.com/adding-keyboard-navigation/. Teaches you on how to add keyboard navigation to a working slideshow plugin.

If I were to do this, would start from there. Then replace the images with actual content. Then apply to actual working sites and ajaxify.

Answer (score 2):

If you analyze the site, actually it is not a scroll. Indeed, it is send a ajax request when you press a key and then update de main container. Also it is updating the URL with the page number. I f you want to make something like that you can study jquery ajax functions(ajax(), .get(), .post()) and effect functions (fadeIn, fadeOut)

You ctake a look here http://www.chazzuka.com/ajaxify-your-web-pages-using-jquery-88/

Answer (score 2):

## *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/owipum/2/edit)*

Down in the code you can find the 'arrow keys navigation'.

```
var slideN = $('.slide').length;
var galW = $('#gallery').width();
var c = 0;

// enlarge the slider element
$('#slider').width(galW*slideN); 

// POPULATE NAVIGATION
for( i=0; i<slideN; i++ ){
    $('#navigation').append('<div class="button">'+(i+1)+'</div>');
}
// MAKE FIRST BUTTON 'active'
$('#navigation .button').eq(0).addClass('curr');


// ADD PREV AND NEXT BTN TO NAVIGATION
$('#navigation').prepend('<div class="nav prev">&#9668;</div>').append('<div class="nav next">&#9658;</div>');

// THE ANIMATION FUNCTION
function slide(){ 
  $('#slider').stop(1).animate({left:'-'+(galW*c)},1000);
  $('.button').eq(c).addClass('curr').siblings().removeClass('curr');
}

// NAVIGATION (numbered) BUTTONS
$('.button').click(function(){
  c = $(this).index()-1;
  slide();
});

// COUNTER HANDLER
function ch(){
   if(c === -1){c = slideN -1; return;}
   c = c % slideN;
}

// PREV/NEXT NAVIGATION
$('.nav').click(function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass('next') ){
    c++; ch(); slide();
  }else{
    c--; ch(); slide(); 
  }      
});

// ARROW KEY NAVIGATION
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {   // if left arrow
            $('.prev').click();
            return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {  // if right arrow
            $('.next').click();
            return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you donøt know how to load with Ajax, you can learn it easily by JQuery-tutorials.
Anyway, the function I would use would be:

```
function () {
$("#TheIdOfYourItem").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000, function() {
 $("TheIdOfTheNewStuff").show("slide, { direction: "left"}, 1000);
});

}
```

"TheIdOfYouritem" will be the stuff you need hidden
"TheIdOfTheNewStuff"... you know ;)